# Json nested parameters

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using data from a Json object to populate a list view. The object has these parameters:

```
"id": "339150749455906", 
"posts": {
"data": [
{
"id": "339150749455906_545370565500589", 
"from": {
  "category": "Food/beverages", 
  "name": "Pepsi", 
  "id": "339150749455906"
}, 
"story": "Pepsi updated their cover photo.", 
"picture": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/942740_545370555500590_46289134_s.jpg", 
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=545370555500590&set=a.365573920146922.72816.339150749455906&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
"icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
"actions": [
  {
    "name": "Comment", 
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/339150749455906/posts/545370565500589"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Like", 
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/339150749455906/posts/545370565500589"
  }
],
```

I want to access the link inside the parameter/key "actions". So far I am using:

```
foreach (var post in postsTaskResult.posts.data)
{
   link = new Uri(string.Format("{0}", (string)post["link"])); 
}
```

However, this only brings the link in the "data". How can I access the other 'link' ?

Comment: how about another loop to iterate over the _actions_ array?
`foreach(var action in post.actions)`

Comment: wrong tags again. better tags will fetch better answers.

Comment: I have used tim's version and it is working. Thanks tim!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var actionLinks = new List<string>();
var actions = post["actions"] as JArray; // if this works then all is well
foreach(var item in actions)
{
    actionLinks.Add((string)item["link"]);
}
```

I think you can also use some fancy Linq with this like

```
var actionLinks = ((JArray)post["actions"])
         .Children<JObject>()
         .Select(a => (string)a["link"])
         .ToList();
```

Very un-tested. Just let me know.